# Why does Fitnesse.UserGuide.QuickReferenceGuide not work locally

Tags: tdd, wiki, fitnesse

I downloaded and installed the FitNesse release from 20110104

The Acceptance tests all run and pass.

Reading through the documentation I arrived at Fitnesse.UserGuide.QuickReferenceGuide, but this page didn't render correctly. It claims that loads of variables are undefined (HDR, DIVend, pagePATH etc. etc.)

Went back to fitnesse.org and the page renders fine.

The diffs were slightly different, so I copied the version from the web onto my local installation, but it still renders incorrectly (see image). Any help would be appreciated.

[image: incorrectly rendered cheat sheet]

You can see the wiki markup at [fitnesse.org](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.QuickReferenceGuide?edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue, please read the following thread:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/fitnesse/message/16772

It has to do with the introduction of a new parser in release 20110104 of fitnesse